# Ler data inicial e final de um evento no banco de dados

Tags: c#

Fiz uma tela de relatório para ler alguns valores de um banco de dados. Quando digito por exemplo 01/05/2017(data inicio) e 31/05/2017 (data final) o banco me retorna como queria. Mas quando digito a data final por exemplo (01/06/2017) o banco me retorna nulo. O que eu devo fazer?

```
DateTime DT_IN_General = new DateTime();
DateTime DT_OUT_General = new DateTime();

DT_IN_General = Convert.ToDateTime(DateIn.Text);
DT_OUT_General = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOut.Text);

if ((string) LB_Name_Equip.Content != "Selecionar Equipamento") {

 if (DateIn.Text != null) {
  if (DateOut.Text != null) {
   if (DT_IN_General < DT_OUT_General) {
    if ((string) LB_Name_Equip.Content == "EL 02") {
     DataGrid_ItemSource_Alarms_And_Events(Class.DataBaseSqlServerEquip.GetReportEvent_Table_EquipAlarmEvent(Convert.ToDateTime(DateIn.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(DateOut.Value), "_EL 02"));
    }

    public static DataTable GetReportEvent_Table_EquipAlarmEvent(DateTime DTIn, DateTime DTOut) {

      DataTable Data = new DataTable();


      try {
       string CommandString = "SELECT * FROM EquipAlarmEvent WHERE Event = 'True' AND DateIn >= '" + DTIn + "' AND DateIn <= '" + DTOut + "' ORDER BY Id DESC;";

       SqlConnection Call = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

       SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(CommandString, ConnectionString);

       Adapter.Fill(Data);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
       Screen.Window_Buffer_Diagnostic.List_Error = ex.ToString();
      }

      return RemoveUnderscoreAndSubscribeDate(Data);
```

Comment: você precisa detalhar sua pergunta. Como saberemos se você não colocou o código? Quanto mais detalhada sua pergunta melhor.

Comment: Recomendo que você faça um [tour] pelo site e veja [ask].

Comment: SELECT * FROM EquipAlarmEvent WHERE Event = 'True' AND DateIn >= '01/04/2017 00:00:00' AND DateIn <= '01/07/2017 00:00:00' ORDER BY Id DESC Aqui o que "peço" pro Banco